# grep for contents AFTER pattern in delimiter

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, regular-expression

say i have a file

```
#cat file.log
abc|123|text1 modesc=bpp123 raw_info=clear
abc|123|text2 modesc=pmk123 severity=minor
abc|123|text3 modesc=pnj123 info=good
```

only want to know what words in print $3 appear after "modesc=" untill space,

I would much prefer that the output of that command looked like this:

```
abc|123|bpp123
abc|123|pmk123
abc|123|pnj123
```

Using bash, I would like to just print out where $3 just get the word after "modesc=". Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/[^|]*modesc=\([^ ]*\).*$/\1/' file
abc|123|bpp123
abc|123|pmk123
abc|123|pnj123
```

This uses `sed` to replace the whole last field with the contents after `modesc=` up to the next space.

---

```
$ awk -F '|' -vOFS='|' '{ sub(".*modesc=", "", $3); sub(" .*", "", $3)} 1' file
abc|123|bpp123
abc|123|pmk123
abc|123|pnj123
```

This `awk` program modifies the third column with two substitutions.  The first removes everything up to and including `modesc=`, and the second one removes everything after the first remaining space.  The lone `1` at the end will cause `awk` to print the modified record (this may be replaced by `{ print }`).

---

To *only* get the string after `modesc=` from the third column of the original data (and not anything else), you may use either of the above commands and then pipe that through `cut -d '|' -f3`, or you may use

```
sed 's/.*modesc=\([^ ]*\).*$/\1/' file
```

or

```
awk -F '|' -vOFS='|' '{ sub(".*modesc=", "", $3); sub(" .*", "", $3); print $3 }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can use multiply delimiters and do it quite sample:

```
awk -F'[|= ]' ' {print $1"|" $2"|" $5}' /tmp/file.log
```

In above line pipe `|`, equiv sign `=` and space   are delimiters.

You can define output delimiter explicitly like this:

```
awk -F'[|= ]' 'BEGIN { OFS="|"}  {print $1,$2,$5}' /tmp/file.log
```

Comment: The print $1 $2 $5 need the commas for the OFS to take effect. Right now they'll be just concatenated.

Comment: @RakeshSharma, right, will correct it :)

Comment: Nice solution. The assumption is that the order of the words in field 3 do not change.

Comment: Right. If the case is not this I expect OP will enter it in to the example input :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F\| '{print $1"|"$2"|"gensub(/modesc=(.*) .*$/,"\\1","g",$3)}' /tmp/file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be less efficient, but the task fits nicely with `cut` and `paste`

```
paste -d '|' <(cut -d'|' -f1-2 file.log) <(cut -d'|' -f3 file.log | grep -oP 'modesc=\K\S+')
```